# Finding the Inverse Laplace transform using the Step and Shift theorems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, laplace-transform

[image]

I want to find the Inverse Laplace Transformation of the function given above. I used the step and shift theorems to come up with an answer. Can someone simply verify the answer. This is my first inverse problem using these two theorems.

**Answer for Review**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks great, just one slight issue (which maybe you just transposed).

You should have:

$$-\dfrac{7}{4}~~\mbox{instead of}~~ -\dfrac{4}{7}$$

Comment: Yes of course I went back and checked and it was a transposition error. Thanks for the verification.

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ +1 Looking forward to POETs Day tomorrow!

Comment: @Amzoti ...and another talk in your already-very-busy month ahead of you!